# Facebook API: user_interests deprecations

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Facebook API user_interests permission will soon be deprecated.  How can I get user interests without calling this permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The endpoint is [removed from version v2.3 on](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/interests). There is no work-around.